# Execute SQL-Statement from File with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, mysql2

I have an *.sql file which is autogenerated and contains all drop and create information for my database.

Now I want to execute the SQL Statement with ActiveRecord:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute File.read( filename )
```

The error I get is

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `airports`;
```

Followed by the complete content of the *.sql file.

However if I just copy and paste the content of the *.sql into PhpMyAdmin and execute it there it runs without any problem.

Is there a better way of doing it? Do I have to specify the mysql-version somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` sanitizes the input and does not allow running multiple queries in one statement.

One work-around might be splitting the content of the file into single queries and running each of them independently:

```
queries = File.read(filename).split(';')
queries.each { |query| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query) }
```

A more advance version will skip empty conditions. Empty strings can occur because `split` returns an empty string after the last ';'. I would skip such blank query strings like this:

```
queries = File.read(filename).split(';')
queries.each do |query| 
  query.strip!
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query) unless query.empty?
end
```

Comment: As there seemed to be only an empty string at the end I just called queries.pop which is working fine until now.

Comment: To use `pop` is error prone, because it always (and only) removes the last element. Think about malformed files with duplicate ';', with empty lines or missing ';' at the end...