# Executing raw SQL in migrations: keep SQL statements as strings inside a migration or as code inside a separate SQL file?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

In the database, I have multiple materialized views with big definitions. I also have multiple migrations that change the definitions of some of these materialized views using `DROP` and `CREATE` statements. Thus, we often are dropping / recreating the same views over and over, with small changes. These (rather bulky) statements are now stored inside strings:

```
class MyMigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    sql = <<~SQL
      ...
      create materialized view if not exists foo_1 as ... ;
      create materialized view if not exists foo_2 as ... ;
      ...
    SQL
    execute sql
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
```

I am considering switching from this current approach to a different one, where the SQL code is stored inside separate SQL files, for example in `db/migrate/concerns/create_foo_matviews.sql`. The code is read from the file and executed from inside the migrations, like so:

```
class MyMigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    execute File.read(File.expand_path('./concerns/create_foo_matviews.rb', __FILE__))
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
```

The pros of this approach are:

- It is easier to see the differences between the old and the new SQL code using `git diff` (especially important given that materialized views' definitions are big, but the actual changes in migrations are relatively small).
- The SQL file adds syntax highlighting to the SQL code.
- There is less copy/pasted code if I only change the relevant parts in the SQL file.

Are there any problems associated with this proposed approach? If yes, what would be an alternative solution to maximize maintainability?

**See also**

- [Is it possible to use an external SQL file in a Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1228930/967621)
- [Running sql file using rails migration file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42552926/967621)
- [Execute SQL-Statement from File with ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31403426/967621)

Answer (score 3):

I'd leave it in the Migration.

Mainly because the migration then contains everything that actually makes up the DB change.
You would need to have two external SQL files (*up* and *down*) that I need to search/find first before I understand what the migration does.

Depending on the Editor you are using, you will get (limited) syntax highlighting
[image: SQL In Heredoc in VS Code]

The migrations that execute custom SQL would all look the same, just the name of the external file would be different.

What problem are you trying to solve? Just the "bulky" strings? I don't think that this is problem (to be honest once the migration is run, you not go back to it anyhow) that is worth spennding a lot of time on. Just to the simplest thing: SQL in heredoc string.

There are also gems that allow you to create (materialized) views with normal migration code (by adding support for `create_view` or similar) but i'd not add an additional dependency for something this simple.

Also consider changing from *schema.rb* to *structure.sql*, if not yet done.

Comment: I think your last sentence is really the key to this. `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` is the authoritative description of the database. Everything in `db/migrate/` should be short lived, you should be able to delete migrations that are a few months old and have been run everywhere without causing any problems.

Comment: @Pascal, thank you for your suggestions! We already have the description in `structure.sql`. Also, I updated the question emphasizing (a) the definitions of these materialized views are big, and (b) we're dropping / recreating the same ones over and over, with small changes. Not sure how this would affect your answer. Sorry for not being clear in the original post!

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you for your comment. I updated the question emphasizing (a) the definitions of these materialized views are big, and (b) we're dropping / recreating the same ones over and over, with small changes. Not sure how this would affect your comment.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Good that you already have `structure.sql`. I'd still not worry about refactoring or cleanliness in `db/migrate/` that much, I regularly clear it out and use `structure.sql` as the definitive version of my functions, views, check constraints, ...

Comment: @muistooshort I am mostly concerned about the ease of maintenance. For example, `diff`-ing is difficult when the SQL code is in several separate migrations and the SQL code is stored inside strings. When a small part of each matview is changed, and the definitions of matviews are big, and there are many matviews, it is so much easier to just `git diff` the SQL file than to `diff` multiple separate migrations... I agree with you in that I am not concerned about cleanliness in `db/migrate` per se.

Comment: If it works better to keep them separate then do it. Just keep in mind that `structure.sql` contains what's in the database.

Comment: dropping/recreating with small changes: and you would change the underlying file that contains the SQL statements and run it again in a new migration?

If so, this is problematic, as it might make it impossible to run the existing migrations from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you want to create your own helpers to create materialized views, something like `add_index` or `add_column`.

You could make a module named like `MaterializedMigrations` in your lib directory. then you can required it in a initializer and for last you include it in your migration code, like this:

```rb
class MyMigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  include MaterializedMigrations

  def up
    create_materialized_view("name_of_view")
  end
end
```

The helper API is only a suggestion, you could design better API for your use cases.